# Put the section and subsection in headers using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, article

I would like have the next headers in the two-side article class :

-if the page is odd: "X.The name of the section" at the left (inner) and "number page" at right (outer)

-if the page is even: "page number" at left and "X.x. the name of the subsection" at right,

where X and X.x means the correspondign numbers of the section and subsection.

I try the next code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\arabic{page}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\toc

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

But \leftmark show always the word "Índice" (index, table of contents; I'm from Spain). Why? How can I do it?

The example fails when i add:    "input{preambulo}", where preambulo is the next code:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CODIFICACIÓN DE ARCHIVO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% El paquete inputenc sirve para que el compilador pueda interpretar los acentos en espaniol de forma estandar, dependiendo del sistema operativo hay que darle una configuracion diferente:
%
%para windows se escribe:
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%-
%para linux se escribe:
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
% o
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%-
%para mac se escribe:
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   IDIOMAS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% El paquete babel sirve para separar correctamente las palabras en muchos idiomas, aquií­ esta configurado con espaniol (spanish). Tambien sirve para que el Ií­ndic etenga tií­tulo "Indice" en lugar de "Contents".
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel} 



%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AJUSTE PÁGINA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUENTES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% El paquete fontenc sirve para incluir acentos
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
% Aumenta la calidad del pdf
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
% Si dejamos comentado el paquete de abajo utilizaremos la fuente por defecto
% si se quita el comentario se usa sans. Se puede usar times, y otras opciones que se dejan comentadas. 
%\usepackage{sans}
%\usepackage{palatino}
%\usepackage{fbb}
%\usepackage{bera}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{libertine} 
% letras tachadas
%\usepackage{slashed}
%\usepackage{lettrine}% The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text



%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ENCABEZADOS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% esta es una posible configuración para el encabezado. 
%Si se comentan estas dos lineas no habrá encabezado y la numeración de página aparecerá abajo de cada hoja. En la página donde se llame a \maketitle no se coloca encabezado.
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Editar las páginas de los capítulos
%\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section
%\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAQUETES DE MATENÁTICAS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% fuentes para escribir sí­mbolos
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[subnum]{cases}
%derivdas parciales
%\usepackage{esdiff}
% cancelar miembros de uan ecuación
%\usepackage{cancel}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLAS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paquetes para el manejo de tablas, creación de filas y columnas unidas.
%\usepackage{multirow} 
% Control de color en tablas muy versátil.
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{multicol} 
%delimitar las columnas con una línea
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
%elegir el color de la línea que delimitia las columnas
%\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{red}}
% Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
%\usepackage{booktabs} 


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GRÁFICOS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% El paquete graphicx sirve para controlar figuras con \includegraphics.
%\usepackage{graphicx}
% Esta linea indica el lugar (path) en el cual se encuentra la carpeta donde colocamos imágenes, para ahorrar colocarlo en cada
% llamado de una imagen en el documento.
%\graphicspath{{./Imagenes/}}
% Estos paquetes permiten colocar varias figuras en el entorno "figure" como subfiguras (cualquiera de los dos).
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig} 


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HIPERVÍNCULOS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% paquete para marcar los hiperví­nculos en i­ndice y referencias
%\usepackage{hyperref}
% Para citar referencias  
%\usepackage{cite} 
%\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=cyan, citecolor=green, linkcolor=blue} % Pinta con color las referencias
%\usepackage[hypcap]{caption} % Las imágenes tienen hiperreferencia y se ven completas y no solo la leyenda. 
% Para hacer hiperreferencias a páginas web
\usepackage{url} 


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NUMERACIÓN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paquete que cambia como se representa la numeración de las imágenes, ecuaciones y tablas
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
% Ahora se nombran por sección reiniciando el conteo en cada sección
%\counterwithin{figure}{section}
%\counterwithin{equation}{section}
%\counterwithin{table}{section}
%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
%==================


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAFÍA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Para agregar al índice las refencias
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind} 
% Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 
% Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} 


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OTROS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usepackage{dirtytalk} % Paquete para facilitar la notación de citas con el comando \say{}

%El paquete colortbl sirve para darle color a las tablas
%\usepackage{colortbl}

% Este paquete se utiliza para generar texto de relleno.
%\usepackage{blindtext}
```

Thanks

PD1: What's about titlesec package?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}`.

If you remove this from my code it works. Otherwise, it fails.

Comment: Your code works regardless of the presence of `tocbibind`, though I had to replace `\toc` with `\tableofcontents`, as the former is undefined.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. With tcbibind it shows "INDICE", not the subsection. ANd yes, there is a mistake, sorry.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see now. It works fine if you load `tocbibind` *after* `\pagestyle{fancy}`, but if you load that package before setting the page style, it doesn't work. You didn't say where in the code you placed your preamble file, so I didn't spot that at first.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can do it this way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}     
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}     
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}     
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}     
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Titel
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}                 %counter =1
\section{Section name}
first page
\subsection{Subsection name}
firstpage \newpage

second page \newpage
... next page
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below mentioned code. It will display the name of the section and page number in the header part.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1} }
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} }
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\rightmark}} }
```

Comment: This code only shows number page in the right header.

Comment: What exactly you want in header and footer. Please be specific.

Comment: -if the page is odd: "X.The name of the section" at the left (inner) and "number page" at right (outer) -if the page is even: "page number" at left and "X.x. the name of the subsection" at right, all foots clear

Comment: @Dog_69 . Check the edited code. Its perfectly working in my case for both the odd and even pages of a book.